# MySQL Wrong Record showing Even if record not in the database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i am currently facing an issues with mysql query to database. i have two table one for the person name and one for the results and i want to get all record where my table has similar persone name.

here is example:

```
SELECT r.*, p.note FROM `result` AS r
  JOIN person AS p ON r.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', p.name, '%')
     GROUP BY r.id
```

so here some record are showing which is not in person table and i test on PHPMYADMIN and filter data in search "i am ti" and i see a result is filtered even this is not available in anywhere in the row. please take a look on image for understanding.

Please let me know what is the problem and if i am making any mistake.

[image: phpmyadmin filter features]

Comment: How are the two tables related? Is it by name?

Comment: yes with name..

Comment: On your query if you do `JOIN person AS p ON r.name = p.name` instead of `JOIN person AS p ON r.name`, does it give you different results?

Comment: it give me the result but in including some additional row which is not listed in person table. like i shaw in image in phpmyadmin also show the wrong record why this happening.?

Comment: The filter rows search box in phpmyadmin searches for what you write in all columns. You can see that `name` column has all the letters from the search you're doing. I think that's what's happening.